# synchronizationLockException object is not synchronised - parse login issue

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas, thread-synchronization

I am getting this synchronizationLockException in facebook canvas app.[image: synchronizationLockException screenshot] 
my issue is something similer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021688/facebook-parse-unity-login-fail-401unauthorized). I have implemented facebook sdk also which is working properly but getting synchronizationLockException when trying to login into parse from this chunk of code.

```
IEnumerator  OnLoggedIn()                                                                          
{                  

    Debug.Log("Logged in. ID: " + FB.UserId);                                            
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ParseUser> logInTask = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync (FB.UserId, FB.AccessToken, FB.AccessTokenExpiresAt);
    while(!logInTask.IsCompleted) 
        yield return null;
    logInTask.ContinueWith (t => {
        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled) {
            Debug.Log ("Parse Login failed");
            Debug.Log ("t.Exception=" + t.Exception);
            foreach (Exception e in logInTask.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
                ParseException parseException = (ParseException)e;
                Debug.Log ("Error message " + parseException.Message);
                Debug.Log ("Error code: " + parseException.Code);
            }
        } else {
            ParseUser userFB = t.Result;
            Debug.Log("--------------------------------------------------------------------------userfb:"+userFB.ObjectId);
            objectId=userFB.ObjectId;
            FB.API("/me", HttpMethod.GET, FBAPICallback);
        }
    });

}
```

this code has been taken from [source code](https://gist.github.com/youminkim/7a22e054823f2baa3463)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the async thread and main thread might be using the variable at the same time .

try this instead

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/438578/variable-access-simulateneously.html